# How to send multiple post requests in same connection using python requests

Tags: python, http, http-post, python-requests

In order to automate user registration in my website, I am using

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://www.dakshnetworks.com:8888/accounts/signup/', data=payload)
```

That is working well. but once the user is registered, i am directing him to another page where he has to set his workplace. So i tried to use

```
 o= requests.post('http://www.dakshnetworks.com:8888/set/', data=payload2)
```

but that is not able to set the workplace of the user returning error 500

```
[01/Jun/2015 17:11:07] "POST /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[01/Jun/2015 17:11:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[01/Jun/2015 17:11:07] "GET /set/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26351
[01/Jun/2015 17:14:40] "POST /set HTTP/1.1" 500 75469
[01/Jun/2015 17:16:16] "POST /set/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126509
```

So how do i maintain the connection so that the server may know that the requests are coming from the same user.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Session()` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) to maintain cookies, so that the server knows it is still the same user:

```
session = requests.Session()
r = session.post('http://www.dakshnetworks.com:8888/accounts/signup/', data=payload)
o = session.post('http://www.dakshnetworks.com:8888/set/', data=payload2)
```

Comment: now i realize that the second request should be an ajax request. how should i do that

Comment: @Rohit: AJAX is just another request. There isn't much of a difference to the *server* there.

Comment: even though I am using session, it is redirecting me to login page when using any method where login is required
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> e= session.get('http://dakshnetworks.com:8888/accounts/login', auth=('48948'
, 'password'))
>>> i = session.get('http://dakshnetworks.com:8888/user/set_interests')

Comment: That's using Basic Auth, are you sure the site doesn't use a login form?

Comment: If Basic Auth works, use that username and password for *every request* or use `session.auth = ('48948', 'password')` to make the session send it every time.

Comment: >>> with requests.session() as s:
...   p = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/accounts/login/', auth=auth)
...   q = s.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/set_interests/', data={'skills': 'management'})
I tried this also: 
>>> a = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8888/user/set_interests', auth=auth, data={'skills': 'management'})
in the first case, session is not persistent and user data is not being extracted. the second one is simply not working

Comment: @Rohit: you'll have to analyse how the site tracks users; Refererer header, cookies, Basic Auth, etc., then replicate that.